# How to load an external PHP library (with multiple folders) in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm working for a solution for days on how to include the PHPCrawl library into Laravel 5.

Here is the installation guide: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/quickstart.html

I tried to load it from a new Namespace called Libraries but I have to add that namespace to all the files included in the library -> it crashes on abstract classes.

I also tried to add it in the `composer.json`, still no luck.

Can anybody provide me with a solution?

Comment: I have not looked at the lib but it sounds like it is not built for composer and you would need to manually generate the manifest(s) file for that library if you wish for it to be installed in laravel using standard methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend Composer. I'm not sure what you added to your `composer.json` file, but you can run `composer require mmerian/phpcrawl` on the command line to pull in [this PHPCrawl composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/mmerian/phpcrawl). Looks to be the most popular (current) Composer version of that library.